# spark select expression available only in R but not in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the name of sparks `selectExpr.html` https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/sparkr/functions/selectExpr.html when using spark with Scala?

## edit

how can I use it in a `withColumn` statement?

```
val scalarInput = 123
df.withColumn("foo", selectExpr("""someHiveUDF( ${scalarInput}, column)"""))
```

fails with
`selectExpr` not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expr` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` is what you want!

Answer (score 1):

The name is exactly the same, [`selectExpr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@selectExpr(exprs:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):

```
def selectExpr(exprs: String*): DataFrame
```

Comment: so it should be provided by default from a dataset. But How can I use this in a withColumn expression then? It does not seem to be available there.